# How to keep the best row in a pandas dataframe satisfying multiple conditions with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
   experiment  replicate  count   fdr
0           a          1     10  0.01
1           a          1      8     0
2           a          1      9     0
```

I would like to group by `experiment` and `replicate` and keep the row that has the minimum `fdr`, but in cases where there are multiple rows with the same minimum `fdr`, use the row with the maximum `count`.

So my expected output would be

```
   experiment  replicate  count   fdr
2           a          1      9     0
```

From reading other posts I can do this based on a single condition with something like:

```
df.groupby(['experiment', 'replicate']).fdr.transform(min)
```

but I can't figure out how to do it with two conditions. I believe I need `apply` instead of `transform`, but I'm still struggling with getting something to work.

Comment: Why the row with `count` = 9 instead of `count` = 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to sort your dataframe in a very specific way. If your last `False` in the `ascending` parameter was changed to `True`, then you would get a different answer, so you should make sure it is sorted like that.

Then, use can use your `groupby` with `idxmin()[0]` to return the index minimum value (`[0]` gets rid of series index so you just get raw value), and then filter the dataframe by that.

```
df = df.sort_values(['experiment', 'replicate', 'fdr', 'count'],
                    ascending=[True, True, True, False])
df[df.index == df.groupby(['experiment', 'replicate']).fdr.idxmin()[0]]

# Per @wwii's comment a slightly cleaner way and likely most syntactical

df.loc[df.groupby(['experiment', 'replicate']).fdr.idxmin(),:]

Out[1]: 
  experiment  replicate  count  fdr
2          a          1      9  0.0
```

Comment: Like yours better David....  Did not realize we were all answering this one

Comment: `df.loc[grouped.fdr.idxmin(),:]`

Answer (score 2):

You could first get the minimum, compare with each row, then get the index with max count and finally filter for that row:

```
cond1 = df.groupby(["experiment", "replicate"]).fdr.transform("min")
row_with_max_count = df.loc[df.fdr.eq(cond1), "count"].idxmax()
df.loc[[row_with_max_count]]

    experiment  replicate   count   fdr
2      a           1           9    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
data = { 'experiment' : ['a', 'a', 'a'],
        'replicate' : [1, 1, 1],
        'count' : [10,8,9],
        'fdr' : [0.01,0,0],}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

gives

```
    experiment  replicate   count   fdr
0   a           1           10      0.01
1   a           1           8       0.00
2   a           1           9       0.00


df.groupby(['experiment', 'replicate']).min('fdr')

                       count    fdr
experiment  replicate       
a           1          8        0.0
```

Comment: It should be returning the third row (with count 9). I want to sort by fdr first and then count as a second condition when fdr is not sufficient.